# Сгруппировать сумму по дням

Tags: mysql

Необходимо написать запрос, который брал бы сумму всех проданных товаров определенного продавца за определенный период и сгруппировать сумму по дням (например: `'2018-02-12' = 560, '2018-02-14' = 1200` и т.д.). Написал такой запрос, но что-то он не работает( Подскажите, пожалуйста, как должен выглядеть запрос?

```
SELECT SUM(oc_ms_order_product_data.seller_net_amt) AS sum 
FROM `oc_ms_order_product_data` 
LEFT JOIN `oc_order` ON(`oc_ms_order_product_data`.`order_id`=`oc_order`.`order_id`) 
WHERE `oc_ms_order_product_data`.`seller_id`='27' 
  AND `oc_order`.`date_added` <= '2018-02-12' 
  AND `oc_order`.`date_added` >= '2018-02-12' 
group by datetime `oc_order`.`date_added`
```

Comment: посмотрите на дату в запросе. дважды указана одна и та же.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(`oc_order`.`date_added`) AS `date`
     , SUM(oc_ms_order_product_data.seller_net_amt) AS `sum` 
FROM      `oc_ms_order_product_data` 
LEFT JOIN `oc_order` ON `oc_ms_order_product_data`.`order_id`=`oc_order`.`order_id`
WHERE `oc_ms_order_product_data`.`seller_id`='27' 
  AND `oc_order`.`date_added` >= '2018-01-01' -- from inclusive
  AND `oc_order`.`date_added` <  '2018-02-12' -- till exclusive
GROUP BY DATE(`oc_order`.`date_added`)
```